# how to edit an NSMutableArray data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this NSMutableArray

```
sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[sections addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Electricity",@"Type",@"0",@"Count", nil]];
    [sections addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Water",@"Type",@"0",@"Count", nil]];
    [sections addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mobile",@"Type",@"0",@"Count", nil]];
    [sections addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Internet",@"Type",@"0",@"Count", nil]];
    [sections addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Fixed Line",@"Type",@"0",@"Count", nil]];
```

and lets say a user choose to change Water count from 0 to 10 how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

`[[sections objectAtIndex:1] setObject:@"10" forKey:@"Count"];`

One more thing. When you create objects with alloc+init, you should release them yourself. So for each `NSMutableDictionary` you have a memory leak (in your code).
Use either `[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:..., nil] autorelease];` or `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:..., nil];` (of course, you can make something like `for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in sections) [dict release];` later, but this looks ugly).